# How to get Adjacency Matrix or pairs from two columns(key, value)?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, graph

I got a dataframe with two columns(key, value)

```py
key,value 
1,A
1,B
2,B
2,C
```

how to get an adjacency matrix or adjacency pairs(connect values if they have the same key), something like

```py
  A B C
A 0,1,0
B 1,0,1
C 0,1,0
```

I tried pandas.crosstab, which works fine on small data,
but got memory error on a big dataframe(3,000,000 rows, 500,000 distinct value). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How big is "big data"? If the dataframe has `n` distinct elements, then the matrix will have size `n²`. This could be huge if `n` is big.

Comment: n is about 500,000, pandas.crosstab will try to allocate a big array which caused the error.